# Redirect the user when he try showing image

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to redirect the user when he tries to show an image in his browser, for example when he put this URL:

> www.mysite.com/image.jpg

he will be redirected to

> www.mysite.com/image.html

but I do not want redirection done in my code when I call the image `<img src = 'www.mysite.com/image.jpg' />`

Comment: please be more specific on how the user would interact with your application and preverably include code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect then you can use PHP for it, here is a link to the code that you should insert to your site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

this is the code:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Just insert this code into the header of the page and it will automatically direct to the URL there. Remember to replace the URL...

Comment: That won't work because an browsing directly to the image won't ever call a page thus no header gets called and your code never executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using .htaccess, so that user cannot access your images in using direct URL in browser

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```